# list index out of range in queue

Tags: python

How can I make it so that I can not add the minimum number of elements to the queue (3 for each type). If I remove or add at least 1 such element, I get an IndexError: list index out of range error. How can I quickly check for the existence of such an element. I tried if but it's too loud

```
class AnimalShelter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cats = []
        self.dogs = []
        self.hamsters = []
        self.order = 0
    
    def add_animal(self, name, kind):
        kind = kind.lower()
        self.order += 1
        
        animal = {"name": name, 
                  "type": kind, 
                  "order": self.order}
        
        if kind == "cat":
            self.cats.append(animal)
        elif kind == "dog":
            self.dogs.append(animal)
        elif kind == "hamster":
            self.hamsters.append(animal)
        else:
            print("Invalid kind.")
    
    def adopt_any(self):
        minOrder = min(self.cats[0]['order'], self.dogs[0]['order'], self.hamsters[0]['order'])
        
        if minOrder == self.cats[0]['order']:
            return self.adopt_cat()      
        if minOrder == self.dogs[0]['order']:
            return self.adopt_dog()   
        if minOrder == self.hamsters[0]['order']:
            return self.adopt_hamster()           
     
    def __adopt_animal__(self, animal_list):
        if len(animal_list) == 0:
            return print("None!")
        else:
            return animal_list.pop(0)
   
    def adopt_cat(self):
        return self.__adopt_animal__(self.cats)
    
    def adopt_dog(self):
        return self.__adopt_animal__(self.dogs)
    
    def adopt_hamster(self):
        return self.__adopt_animal__(self.hamsters)
    
    def show_animals(self):
        print(self.cats)
        print(self.dogs)
        print(self.hamsters)

animalShelter = AnimalShelter()

animalShelter.add_animal("c1", "cat")
animalShelter.add_animal("d1", "dog")

animalShelter.adopt_any()

animalShelter.show_animals()
```

Comment: @JohnGordon
Take one add_animal at the end and see

Comment: _Take one add_animal at the end and see_ I have no idea what actual code that is.  What does "take one" mean?  It would be a lot easier for us to help if you showed the actual code that causes the error, instead of vaguely describing such code and making us guess what you actually meant.

Comment: You are trying to access the `[0]` index of an empty list.  Don't do that and bobs your uncle

Comment: @JohnGordon I have no idea how to check

Comment: an easy solution would be to add all the animal lists into one list and sort them by order number and then take the first one in the list since it would be smallest  `lst = self.cats + self.dogs + self.hamsters`  `order = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x['order'])[0]`  as long as at least one of those lists has an item in it that won't raise an error.  and to be extra safe you could add an `if lst:`  before the sorting to check

Comment: Please provide the complete traceback

Answer (score 0):

```
def adopt_any(self):
    minOrder = min(self.cats[0]['order'], self.dogs[0]['order'], self.hamsters[0]['order'])
```

If there are no cats, `self.cats` will be an empty list, and thus `self.cats[0]` is out of range.  Same with dogs and hamsters.

You should call `min()` only for pet kinds that actually exist:

```
orders = []
if self.cats:
    orders.append(self.cats[0]['order'])
if self.dogs:
    orders.append(self.dogs[0]['order'])
if self.hamsters:
    orders.append(self.hamsters[0]['order'])
minOrder = min(orders)
```